Uso de un procedimiento como funcion en Genexus
Cuando un procedimiento devuelve mas de un parametro, se puede usar ese proc como una funcion?
Ejemplos:
Caso 1: Procedimiento que devuelve 1 solo parametro - Ok (funciona correctamente)
ClienteEsValido(in:ClienteId, out:&esValido)


if ClienteEsValido(123) ...

Caso 2: Procedimiento que devuelve mas de 1 parametro
insertCliente(in:&datosClienteSDT, out:&ClienteId, out:&messages, out:&success)

En este caso, en versiones anteriores de Genexus, se debia hacer el call y luego evaluar las variables de salida en lineas separadas, de forma explicita:
insertCliente(&datosClienteSDT, &ClienteId, &messages, &sucess)
if &success
    if &ClienteId > 0
      ....
    endif
else
    do 'Mostrar errores'
endif

En Gx18, se puede usar de esta forma? : (en este caso, la evaluacion del ultimo parametro de salida &success se estaria haciendo implicitamente.)
if insertCliente(&datosClienteSDT, &ClienteId, &messages)
....
endif


Tendria que funcionarté, gx tiene un comportamiento unico en los procedure, y no tiene nada que ver la posición.
Si es in, no té permite modificar el valor en el procedure, inout envias un valor y puedes modificarlo en el procedure, si es out, inicializa el valor al entrar y puedes modificarlo.

Creo que no entendiste mi pregunta. Es el uso de un proc como funcion, y eso solamente es posible (el menos en versiones anteriores a la 18) cuando el procedimiento devuelve un unico parametro. Se trata de la evaluacion del ultimo parametro dentro de una condicion. De todas formas ya obtuve una respuesta del equipo de desarrollo y no se deberia usar de esa manera cuando el proc devuelve mas de un parametro.

Ni recuerdo cuando existia la llamada udf. De que versions me hablas, de la 9?
